# Multiplicity invalid error when trying to define 1:1 relationships

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, database-design, foreign-keys

So I have a scenario (in ASP.NET MVC) that requires that I have four tables. Three of these need to have a 1:1 relationship with the first table. When I try and run the code first migrations to define this, I get these errors:

```
One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

ANA_ANASection2_Target: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'ANA_ANASection2_Target' in relationship 'ANA_ANASection2'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.
ANA_ANASection3_Target: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'ANA_ANASection3_Target' in relationship 'ANA_ANASection3'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.
ANA_ANASection4_Target: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'ANA_ANASection4_Target' in relationship 'ANA_ANASection4'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.
```

How do I correctly activate these relationships? I don't mind losing data as we are still in development.

My schema is as follows (I'll try and simplify it):

```
public class ANASection2
{
    [Key]
    public int ANASection2Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ANA")]
    public int ANAId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual ANA ANA { get; set; }
}

public class ANASection3
{
    [Key]
    public int ANASection3Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ANA")]
    public int ANAId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual ANA ANA { get; set; }
}

public class ANASection4
{
    [Key]
    public int ANASection4Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ANA")]
    public int ANAId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual ANA ANA { get; set; }
}

public class ANA
{
    public int ANAId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public ANASection2 ANASection2 { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public ANASection3 ANASection3 { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public ANASection4 ANASection4 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You just need to mark your fields as virtual in ANA. That aside, you are using 3 identical classes, why not just add a section ID to your table and reduce it down to 1?

Comment: I've simplified the classess immensely, they all actually have very different fields that don't relate to the question. Have tried to mark them as virtual, does not work.